# Customize Paypal multicurrencyny module - To convert the currency which aren't supported by paypal,into base currency

Tags: php, magento, paypal

Now i have been customizing paypal multicurrency module. Its working well with all currencies which are supported by paypal. For other currencies, it return following error in cart page

**PayPal gateway has rejected request. Currency is not supported (#10605: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details). Internal Error (#10001: Transaction failed due to internal error).**

Can't place order with other currencies. Now i want to convert those currencies which are not supported by paypal into **base currency (USD)** before going to payment gateway page.And make payment with base currency. I have searched a lot, followed some tutorial regarding this.

Finally i got an idea, in where that currency code is set. In **standard.php**, under "**getStandardCheckoutFormFields**", set currency code. In this file "**getConfig**()" method working well. But above method seems not working well

I have checked it by

```
public function getStandardCheckoutFormFields()
{
    echo "standard";
    exit;
    $orderIncrementId = $this->getCheckout()->getLastRealOrderId();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
    ....
    .....
   }
```

After hitting "**place order**" button, it returns to cart page as normal.

Now my question is 1.when this method (**getStandardCheckoutFormFields**()) will call?

2.How to achieve my above task?

If anybody have an idea, please help me guys

Comment: I've used grep command grep -R "getStandardCheckoutFormFields" * and found only two instances 
1) Mage_Paypal_Block_Standard_Redirect
2) Standard.php

and it looks like there is a form in the block 
make a log of the fields in the block
it might give you necessary info

Comment: yeah. Standard.php file is calling in checkout page. But "getStandardCheckoutFormFields" this method which is in standard.php isn't running

Comment: I was refering to the block Mage_Paypal_Block_Standard_Redirect
(Redirect.php) there is a form. try to log the fields in the foreachloop of the form .

Comment: i think, that's also not running.It doesn't created log file. And also i have checked with echo statement tooo.

Comment: I tried it on my local server and I'am able to log the fields.
I logged it in the Block File.|
I see in your question that you have an "exit" statement in the standard.php remove it and try

Comment: Nope. I have checked with exit statement after checked with log files. And one thing, when i have checked with "USD" it redirect to "sand box mode paypal page" But at that time, i didn't get the message like "You will be redirected to the PayPal website in a few seconds." So i think, this page isn't working....

Comment: do you see any exceptions in your logs

Comment: if not I suggest you to debug from redirectAction() on standardcontroller.php

Comment: uff i'm realy sorry to say this. I have checked with "echo "redirection"; exit;". Seems Not working. It make me as mad....

Comment: alright! are you able log those fields now?

Comment: There is no method is running under the "Mage_Paypal_StandardController" file

Comment: yes ofcourse, this line calls the block

$this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('paypal/standard_redirect')->toHtml());

and in the block you'll find the method in a foreach loop

Comment: yeah. I found it. So there is a problem with controller file? do you know how to resolve it? if yes, could you guide me?

Comment: can you redirect to sandbox with USD? with all the messages?

Comment: yeah. Its working with "USD",GBP, EUr currency. After hitting place order button, immediately redirect to sandbox page without any messages like " You will be redirected to the PayPal website in a few seconds."

Comment: so your issue is to checkout with the currencies that are not supported by paypal, and you would like to convert the price for these currencies to base store?

Comment: yeah. before reaching payment page convert those currencies which not supported by paypal, in to base currency

Comment: In the block, inside the foreach loop, make an if condition With an array containg all the currency from your stores not supported by paypal. if(in_array($field['currency_code'],array)),then convert to your base currency.
if you make a log of those fields you'll know which fields require convertion

Comment: yeah. You are right. But that Action method seems not running  :(

Comment: I just found an extension after some digging in google [link](https://github.com/Meabed/Paypal-Multi-Currency-Magento).Hope it helps.

Comment: please print $result variable

Comment: in getStandardCheckoutFormFields() it return $result

Comment: But that method doesn't running... @shivam